# How can I make the set difference insensitive to case?

Tags: ruby

I have a class in which the data is stored as a [set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) and I want to be able to compare objects of that class such that the letter case of the elements is of no matter. For example if the set contains elements that are strings there should be no difference of `"a"` and `"A"`.

To do this I have tried to define the `eql?` method of the set members to be insensitive to case but this has no effect on the method [`-`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-2D) (alias `difference`) in Set. So, how should I go about to make `-` insensitive to case?

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
require 'set'

class SomeSet
  include Enumerable

  def initialize; @elements = Set.new; end

  def add(o)
    @elements.add(o)
    self
  end

  def each(&block)              # To enable +Enumerable+
    @elements.each(&block)
  end

  def difference(compared_list)
    @elements - compared_list
  end
end

class Element
  attr_reader :element

  def initialize(element); @element = element; end

  # This seems to have no effect on +difference+
  def eql?(other_element)
    element.casecmp(other_element.element) == 0
  end
end

set1 = SomeSet.new
set2 = SomeSet.new
set1.add("a")
set2.add("A")

# The following turns out false but I want it to turn out true as case
# should not matter.
puts set1.difference(set2).empty?
```

Comment: one obvious workaround is to convert all strings to lower/upper case when adding to the sets

Comment: @akonsu I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't using `eql?` on Set elements make insertion O(n)?

Comment: Update: `eql?` will not make insertion O(n). See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, firstly, you're just storing strings from `SomeSet#add`, you need to store an instance of `Element`, like so:

```
def add(o)
  @elements.add(Element.new(o))
  self
end
```

And you need to implement a `hash` method in your `Element` class.

You can convert `Element#@element` to lowercase, and pass on its hash.

```
def hash
  element.downcase.hash
end
```

Full code and demo: http://codepad.org/PffThml2

Edit: For my O(n) insertion comment, above:

Insertions are O(1). From what I can see, `eql?` is only used with the `hash` of 2 elements is same. As we're doing `hash` on the downcased version of the element, it will be fairly well distributed, and `eql?` shouldn't be called much (if it is called at all).

Comment: Oops, the first thing was a mistake I made in boiling down the problem to a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> The equality of each couple of elements is determined according to Object#eql? and Object#hash, since Set uses Hash as storage.

Perhaps you need to implement Object#hash as well.

```
require 'set'

class String2
  attr_reader :value

  def initialize v
    @value = v
  end

  def eql? v
    value.casecmp(v.value) == 0
  end

  def hash
    value.downcase.hash
  end
end

set1 = Set.new
set2 = Set.new
set1.add(String2.new "a")
set2.add(String2.new "A")

puts set1.difference(set2).empty?
```

Comment: How would one got about to implement that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I was not able to reopen String class to avoid using my custom class String2. For some reason my overloaded comparison operators are not called when I add a string to a set.