# a set of strings and reopening String

Tags: ruby

In an attempt to answer this question: [How can I make the set difference insensitive to case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994295/how-can-i-make-the-set-difference-insensitive-to-case), I was experimenting with sets and strings, trying to have a case-insensitive set of strings. But for some reason when I reopen String class, none of my custom methods are invoked when I add a string to a set. In the code below I see no output, but I expected at least one of the operators that I overloaded to be invoked. Why is this?

EDIT: If I create a custom class, say, String2, where I define a hash method, etc, these methods do get called when I add my object to a set. Why not String?

```
require 'set'

class String
  alias :compare_orig :<=>
  def <=> v
    p '<=>'
    downcase.compare_orig v.downcase
  end

  alias :eql_orig :eql?
  def eql? v
    p 'eql?'
    eql_orig v
  end

  alias :hash_orig :hash
  def hash
    p 'hash'
    downcase.hash_orig
  end
end

Set.new << 'a'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add) for `Set`, it uses a simple hash for storage:

```
def add(o)
  @hash[o] = true
  self
end
```

So it looks like what you need to do instead of opening `String` is open `Set`. I haven't tested this, but it should give you the right idea:

```
class MySet < Set
  def add(o)
    if o.is_a?(String)
      @hash[o.downcase] = true
    else
      @hash[o] = true
    end
    self
  end
end
```

**Edit**

As noted in the comments, this can be implemented in a much simpler way:

```
class MySet < Set
  def add(o)
    super(o.is_a?(String) ? o.downcase : o)
  end
end
```

Comment: A simple `super(o.is_a?(String) ? o.downcase : o)` might be a better idea.

Comment: thanks. that works, yes. If I create a custom class, say, String2, where I define a hash method, etc, these methods do get called when I add my object to a set. Why? (I edited my question).

Comment: Ruby source (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1195) might give a clue. It looks like `String`s get special treatment as hash keys in MRI.